# How to hook an exe function?

Tags: c++, winapi, hook

I need to get something from a program. And with the help of ollydbg and IDA, I found the "thing" I can get is in a function called `sub_HEXHEX`.

Now I know how to hook a function from Dll like `DrawTextA` or other one.
I need to get function address with

```
HMODULE hmod = LoadLibrary(L"User32.dll");
GetProcAddress(hmod, "DrawTextA")
```

But when I need to hook this `sub_HEXHEX`, I confused. I can get that exe's HANDLE, I know the function's Address (that 0x00HEXHEX), but there's no `GetProcAddress` I can use. I tried use `HANDLE + 0x00HEXHEX` as function's address, but I think im wrong with 'offset' things.

Here is what I did

```
DWORD dwPid = GetCurrentProcessId();  
hProcess = OpenProcess(PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS, 0, dwPid);  
OldA2ECB0 = (sub_A2ECB0)((HMODULE)hProcess + 0xA2ECB0);  
pfOldA2ECB0 = (FARPROC)OldA2ECB0;
```

And sub_A2ECB0

```
typedef int(*sub_A2ECB0)(LPCSTR param1, int param2);
```

[image: Function in IDA]

But pfOldA2ECB0 will be NULL.
My knowledge is poor with C++ and Win32 (English, too), so its toooooo difficult for me.

Comment: What do you mean by there's no `GetProcAddress` you can use?

Comment: @jkb the target function is not an exported function in a DLL, it is a function inside the EXE. `GetProcAddress()` can't be used to get the address of such functions.

Comment: Remy answer your question, thats what I mean. Thanks.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Ah, I was thinking that `sub_HEXHEX` was perhaps the name of a function exported by the exe rather than a name generated by the debugging tools.

Comment: How are you going to call this function? You are going to need to have code executing in the other process. Do you have a plan for that?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I want to hook this function, just like hook DrawTextA. I want to get a param in this function, after I get the param's value, I call this function manually. I will not change anything, just want to get a bool value, this value is important for my program. Anything happened in my dll which inject into target program.

Comment: So use a hooking library then. For instance detours.

Comment: If you know the relative virtual address (RVA) of your function, then you can calculate its address in your process' address space using `module_base + RVA`. If that's not working for you, then you are doing it wrong. Since we cannot see that code, there's nothing we can do to help.

Comment: A process handle is not a module handle. Adding a memory offset to a process handle is a meaningless operation. You need to call [GetModuleHandle](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/libloaderapi/nf-libloaderapi-getmodulehandlew) instead. Once you drop the C-style casts, the compiler is going to help you. Besides, your function pointer `typedef` is missing a calling convention.

Comment: Thank you all for help. I'm learning on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I understand, and I do believe I understand correctly what you want is **internal hooking**.

I can show you how to do this in 3 simple steps.

These are the things you must understand:

- The function shown in IDA **is not exported**, thus you cannot use GetProcAddress()
- You must be **within the context** of the remote process to hook internal functions
- You cannot use libraries like Detours, you must have your own method/function for hooking

These are the steps you must do:

1. Be withing the context of the remote process, simplest method: inject your dll.
2. Get the address offset from IDA, in your case is 00A2ECB0.
3. Simply apply the hook once inside the remote process:

   //0xE8 instruction is a relative call instruction
   SetCompleteHook(0xE8,0x00A2ECB0,&YOUR_OWN_FUNCTION);

Helper:

```
void SetCompleteHook(BYTE head,DWORD offset,...)
{
    DWORD OldProtect;

    VirtualProtect((void*)offset,5,PAGE_EXECUTE_READWRITE,&OldProtect);

    if(head != 0xFF)
    {
        *(BYTE*)(offset) = head;
    }

    DWORD* function = &offset+1;

    *(DWORD*)(offset+1) = (*function)-(offset+5);

    VirtualProtect((void*)offset,5,OldProtect,&OldProtect);
}
```

And that's it really, it's as simple and straightforward as possible in your scenario.

You can go further of course and perform much more complex internal hooking, but for your learning purpose this is a massive step ahead and starting point.

Enjoy!

Comment: I tried what you told and I made it,many thanks! But I found a new problem, that application now show an error `external exception C000001D`, and I think the reason is that I'm not calling it's `A2ECB0()` back. I did some search but until now I cant solve that.

Comment: Well it depends what that function does, you must check in IDA to see what it returns. You must also make sure that you are not breaking the function. The application can also show an exception if you hooked the function and it did not expect it to be... there are many variables. All you can do is test. You can also test with different opcode like 0xE9.

Comment: I'm testing with `((int(*)(DWORD *a1, int a2))0x00A2ECB0)(param1,param2)`.  And I will learn more about asm, many thanks.

Comment: No problem, however if you need more help then you must put your code on pastebin or something.